# Error when I try to convert Corine Land Cover 2000 tiff to shapefile in QGIS 2.10.1 or clip CLC2000 by a polygon

Tags: qgis, raster, error, clip

I want to clip Corine Land Cover 2000 tiff by a polygon or to convert it to shapefile in QGIS 2.10.1.
So far I have tried the following always getting an error message that **'ascii' codec can't encode** some **characters**. I suppose it has to do with the format of my tiff or something... Could you please guide me to what does this mean and how can I proceed with my task?

**Toolbox: GDAL extraction: clip raster by extent**

```
Algorithm Clip raster by extent starting...
GDAL command:
gdal_translate -of GTiff -projwin 5240999.6612 2201224.60925 5459830.9809
1991907.69475 C:/Users/.../qgis_data/g100_00/g100.tif
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\068103c23cef469fbf7f44376e40dbb4\OUTPUT.tif 
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 118-127: ordinal not in 
range(128)
See log for more details
```

**Toolbox: GDAL extraction: clip raster by mask layer**

but I get this *error message*:

```
Algorithm Clip raster by mask layer starting...
GDAL command:
gdalwarp -q -of GTiff -dstnodata -9999 -cutline C:/Users/.../qgis_data/setset.shp
-crop_to_cutline C:/Users/.../qgis_data/g100_00/g100.tif
C:\Users\...\.qgis2\processing\scripts\sda.tif
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 78-87: ordinal not in range(128)
See log for more details
```

**Toolbox: GDAL conversion: vectorize raster layer**

but I get this *error message*:

```
Algorithm Polygonize (raster to vector) starting...
GDAL command:
cmd.exe /C gdal_polygonize.bat C:/Users/....qgis_data/g100_00/g100.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile"  
C:\Users\....\.qgis2\processing\scripts\vect.shp vect DN 
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 62-71: ordinal not in range(128)
See log for more details
```

Comment: Why don't you dowload CLC vector format directly?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some characters that are not latin. For example greek characters in your username of your account or a folder with greek characters. Create a new username with latin characters and/or make sure that all your folders' names have latin characters too.